# Deploy applications to Azure

Tags: azure, cloud

At the company that i work, they deploy applications to azure using Azure App Services.
This involves creating the App service manually, and setting up the pipelines manually.

My question is if there is another way to host and run applications in Azure without using App Services?

The reason for this is that i don't like the manually work when setting up a app service and all it's configuration.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need is setting up CI/CD pipelines for your application to create resource(AppService in this case) and deploy on them.

If you are new to Azure Devops, i would highly recommend to explore [**Devops starter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/overview) service to deploy your application with few clicks and see how it creates resources and pipelines automatically

On the 2nd question, there are many compute options available on Azure such as Virtual Machines , AKS (Containers Orchestration) , Container instances etc.

You can explore those compute options using the decision tree **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree)**

Comment: I have thought about container based applications, but AKS seems to heavy for this. Maybe a "lighter" tool then AKS that is pretty simple ut use?

Comment: Then look at Container Instances

Comment: Is it recommended to host APIs on a Container Instance?

Comment: yeah you can host it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview also look at my slides for understanding on compute options https://slides.com/sajeetharan/computeazure